# Microservices - system desgin - Node.js+React framework + Mongo DB on Azure

Tags: microservices

We are looking to build system for micro services (around 8 micro services built on node.js + react  for now ) while production is already running with Azure Kubernetes. But we looking to build without Kubernetes for QA environment. 
Please guide us on infrastructure requirement on Azure without K8S/AKS, just with VM and open software.

Thanks,
Arul

Comment: you can use azure app services for this, there is provision for nodejs there in azure

Comment: Thanks, Will it be cost effective than build on VM ?